# File structure to multidimensional array

Tags: php, directory, iteration

I need to store all directories and files in multidimensional array for a given location (sample : /path/to/folder) . It should include the sub folders as well no matter how deep.

**Edited :**

I tried with php [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and it gave me following results,

code :

```
$dir    = '/path/to/folder';
$files = scandir($dir);
print_r($files);
```

results :

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => folder1
    [3] => file1
    .....
)
```

What I need is to get the content inside the folder1 and do it continuously till I get complete folder structure with all files.

P.S : I need to remove "." and ".." from the result array too.

Comment: do you tried anything?

Comment: I found something and I just need to share my knowledge among the community

Comment: You can post the link or just mention an abstract of the approach...

Comment: Have a look at the RecursiveDirectoryIterator object in the Standard Php Library (SPL). http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Comment: Edit the question so that I can undownvote

Comment: I have edited the question, please review it again hence my account is suspended for ask questions due to down vote the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

for file listing php provide [readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) and [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) functions.

I preferred sccandir since it's new(php 5>) and we can use following recursive function for this.

Need to provide the directory path (/path/to/your/folder) as a parameter and it will return multidimensional array with folder structure.

```
function dirToArray($dir) {
    $result = array();
    $cdir = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($value,array(".","..")))  {
            if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)){
                $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
            } else {
                $result[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: before providing full code, lets see what OP tried and then you can improve or provide new method...

Comment: I hope this will help to someone

Comment: @Akam: the asker and the answerer are the same!

Comment: You ask a question and then immediately answer it? Why even ask it? -1

Comment: Yes, you can, and it is described as good practice in the stackoverflow help pages.

Comment: oh this is another scenario :) I will undownvote the question

Comment: @Dale: [**Is it okay to answer my own question?**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Totally look like rep whoring to me, no need to ask, no need to answer.

Comment: @Dale: i think its ok, most of good questions here asked intentionally!

Comment: @Dale: Then why do you take the burden to downvote? Nobody is expected to upvote anything, but good questions and good answers, supported by facts, should be upvoted no matter who asked or answered them. Don't like an answer? Give a better one, or improve the existing ones. Don't like the way the question is asked? Improve the question! But don't whine about that 5 or 10 nonsense points that don't buy you anything!

Comment: Sorry I thought the point of this site was to ask for legitimate help not just ask questions so you can answer them

Comment: This is the alternative I'm looking for. I tried using another solution I found around earlier, and though that's a shorter function I couldn't use it since that uses glob() which doesn't work properly for subdirectories with square braces "[ ]" in filenames.